# Multi-threading in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm new to Android and Java. I'm trying to download 1000 plus images. I don't want to do that serially in a `UI` thread as that will be slow. Hence, I implemented **`multi-threading`** using thread and runnable in the below manner.

The for-loop will be called 1000 plus times. So is it an efficient way of achieving it? Will the `OS` manage the thread pool by its own?

```
private void syncS3Data() {
    tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        for (final AWSSyncFile f : awsSyncData.getFiles()) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    beginDownload(f);
                }

            }).start();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        showMessage("Error:" + ex.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can implement some solution in Java to allow only a specific amount of runnable to execute at the same time. In Android, I don't know it there is a specific implementation. See about [Thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) (the entire subject is good to read), like [newFixedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-)

Comment: it is better to use pagination functionality  when its comes to large amount of data . and  you can use asynctask

Comment: If you only want to download images. You can use `glide` library or there are lots of libs to do that. just google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for Sure you can't do that in MainThread (UI Thread) because if you did, the application will not be responding.. and then it will be killed by system, you can use AsyncTask class in order to do what do you need but i prefer to use intentservice 
However you have to use Intentservice it's a worker thread (long operation) but be noted intentservice will not execute anything until it finish the current task, if you need to download it in parallel then you have to use Service it works with UI Thread so you need asyncTask in order to perform the action but make sure of calling stopSelf() unlike intentService it will be stopped once it finish

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating threads for each download, create one thread and use that for downloading all images.

You can use AsyncTask Refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<SomeObject, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(SomeObject... objs) {

        for (final AWSSyncFile f : obj.getFiles()) {
           beginDownload(f);
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
       //Task Completed
    }

new DownloadFilesTask().execute(someObj);
```

Comment: I have read about AsyncTask. As far as I could understand, the above method will be slower as we are using only one background thread for all the downloads. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, but creating separate thread for each file is not an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had developed an e-commerce app before and have encountered a similar problem in which I had to download some 200+ images for each category.The way I did it was using a loop within an AsyncTask and after each download was completed the image was displayed at the relevant place using the onProgessUpdate() function.I can't share the actual code,so i will give a skeleton example.

```
public class DownloadImages extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
  File image;
  protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
      //download the image here and lets say its stored in the variable file
      //call publishProgress() to run onProgressUpdate()


    }
  protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
  {
     //use the image in variable file to update the UI
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this require the creation of multiple AsyncTasks. I understand each AsyncTask is equivalent to one Thread. Putting the for loop inside the AsyncTask won't be very efficient, I believe.

Comment: I used one AsyncTask and put the loop inside that,because i think a loop in an AsyncTask will be more efficient than creating multiple AsyncTasks (or threads).